# Matplotlib clearing old axis labels when re-plotting data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got a script wherein I have two functions, `makeplots()` which makes a figure of blank subplots arranged in a particular way (depending on the number of subplots to be drawn), and `drawplots()` which is called later, drawing the plots (obviously). The functions are posted below.

The script does some analysis of data for a given number of 'targets' (which can number anywhere from one to nine) and creates plots of the linear regression for each target. When there are multiple targets, this works great. But when there's a single target (i.e. a single 'subplot' in the figure), the Y-axis label overlaps the axis itself (this does not happen when there are multiple targets).

Ideally, each subplot would be square, no labels would overlap, and it would work the same for one target as for multiple targets. But when I tried to decrease the size of the y-axis label and shift it over a bit, it appears that the actual axes object was drawn *over* the previously blank, square plot (whose axes ranged from 0 to 1), and the old tick mark labels are still visible. I'd like to have those old tick marks removed when calling `drawplots()`. I've tried changing the `subplot_kw={}` arguments in `makeplots`, as well as removing `ax.set_aspect('auto')` from `drawplots`, both to no avail. Note that there are also screenshots of various behaviors at the end, also.

```
def makeplots(targets, active=actwindow):

    def rowcnt(y):
        rownumb = y//3 if (y%3 == 0) else y//3+1
        return rownumb

    def colcnt(x):
        if x <= 3: colnumb = x
        elif x == 4: colnumb = 2
        else: colnumb = 3
        return colnumb

    numsubs = len(targets)
    numrow, numcol = rowcnt(numsubs), colcnt(numsubs)

    if numsubs >= 1:
        if numsubs == 1:
            fig, axs = plt.subplots(num='LOD-95 Plots', nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize = [8,6], subplot_kw={'adjustable': 'box', 'aspect': 1})
            # changed 'box' to 'datalim'
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(num='LOD-95 Plots', nrows=numrow, ncols=numcol, figsize = [numcol*6,numrow*6], subplot_kw={'adjustable': 'box', 'aspect': 1})
        fig.text(0.02, 0.5, 'Probit score\n    $(\sigma + 5)$', va='center', rotation='vertical', size='16')
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Error generating plots [call: makeplots({targets},{active}) - invalid numsubs value]')

    axs = np.ravel(axs)
    for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
        ax.set_title(f'Limit of Detection: {targets[i]}', size=11)
        ax.grid()
    return fig, axs
```

and

```
def drawplots(ax, dftables, color1, color2):
    y = dftables.probit
    y95 = 6.6448536269514722
    logreg = False
    regfun = lambda m, x, b : (m*x) + b
    regq = scipy.stats.linregress(dftables.qty,y)
    regl = scipy.stats.linregress(dftables.log_qty,y)
    if regq.rvalue**2 >= regl.rvalue**2:
        regression = regq
        x_label = 'input quantity'
        x = dftables.qty
    elif regq.rvalue**2 < regl.rvalue**2:
        regression = regl
        x_label = '$log_{10}$(input quantity)'
        x = dftables.log_qty
        logreg = True
    slope, intercept, r = regression.slope, regression.intercept, regression.rvalue
    r2 = r**2
    lod = (y95-intercept)/slope
    xr = [0, lod*1.2]
    yr = [intercept, regfun(slope, xr[1], intercept)]
    regeqn = "y = "+str(f"{slope:.2e}")+"x + "+str(f"{intercept:.3f}")

    if logreg:
        lodstr = f'log(LOD) = {lod:.2f}' if lod <= 100 else f'log(LOD) = {lod:.2e}'
    elif not logreg:
        lodstr = f'LOD = {lod:.2f}' if lod <= 100 else f'LOD = {lod:.2e}'
#        raise ValueError(f'Error raised calling drawplots()')


    ax.set_xlabel(x_label, fontweight='bold')
    ax.plot(xr, yr, color=color1, linestyle='--') # plot regression line
    ax.plot(lod, y95, marker='D', color=color2, markersize=7) # plot point for LoD
    ax.plot(xr, [y95,y95], color=color2, linestyle=':') # horizontal crosshair
    ax.plot([lod,lod],[0, 7.1], color=color2, linestyle=':') # vertical crosshair
    ax.scatter(x, y, s=81, color=color1, marker='.') # actual data points
    ax.annotate(f"{lodstr}", xy=(lod,0.1),
                xytext=(0.9*lod,0.5), fontsize=8, arrowprops = dict(facecolor='black', headlength=5, width=2, headwidth=5))
    ax.set_aspect('auto')
    ax.set_xlim(left=0)
    ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
    ax.plot()
    if logreg: lod = 10 ** lod

    return r2, lod, regeqn, logreg
```

The context they're called in:

```
fig, axs = makeplots(targets)
wg.SetForegroundWindow(actwindow)

with open(outName, 'a+') as f:
    print(f"Lower Limit of Detection Analysis on {dt} at {tm}\n", file=f)
    for i, tars in enumerate(targets):
        data[tars] = stripThousands(data[tars])
#        logans = checkyn(f"Analyze {tars} using log10(concentration/quantity)? (y/n): ")
        for idx, val in enumerate(qtys):
            tables[i,idx,2] = hitrate(val,data,tars)
            tables[i,idx,3] = norm.ppf(tables[i,idx,2])+5

        printtables[tars] = pd.DataFrame(tables[i,:,:], columns=["qty","log_qty","probability","probit"])
        # construct dataframes from np.arrays and drop
        #     rows with infinite probit values:
        dftables[tars] = pd.DataFrame(tables[i,:,:], columns=["qty","log_qty","probability","probit"])
        dftables[tars].probit.replace([np.inf,-np.inf],np.nan, inplace=True)
        dftables[tars].dropna(inplace=True)


        r2, lod, eqn, logreg = drawplots(axs[i], dftables[tars], cbcolors[i], cbcolors[i+5])
```

[image: No old tick marks, but y-label overlaps the y axis]
[image: y-label is fine, but original 'default' ticks and labels visible and undesired on X axis (and at the top of the subplot)]
[image: Works fine when analyzing multiple targets, though the y-label could be a little closer...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear the axes in each iteration using [**`pyplot.cla()`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.cla.html).

You posted a lot of code, so I'm not 100% sure of the best location to place it in your code, but the general idea is to clear the axes before each new plot.

Here is a minimal demo without `cla()`:

```py
x = [[1,2,3], [3,2,1]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for index, data in enumerate(x):
    ax.plot(data)
```

[image: without cla()]

And with `cla()`:

```py
for index, data in enumerate(x):
    ax.cla()
    ax.plot(data)
```

[image: with cla()]

Comment: Sorry, it's a really long, involved script so I tried to pare it down as much as possible while still providing necessary info. Basically, first `drawplots(targets)` gets called (`targets` just being a list of the column headers serving as the y-values for each graph to be plotted) and a blank figure with blank subplots/axes in the right configuration is generated. Then some calculations are done on each dataset/'target' column and `drawplots` is called iteratively to plot each graph. It was the easiest way to get the layout right, but the initial plots are irrelevant. I'll give cla() a try!

Comment: Hm, no dice. Problem is, I don't know what the x limits will be before calling `drawplots()`, so when calling `makeplots()`, the basic square plots (both axes from 0 to 1, with tick marks every 0.2 units). The y-axis will never be more than 8, so I could set that manually, but the x-axis could range from 0 to 1.4 or from 0 to 100,000. I stuck ax.cla() in the `drawplots()` def right before `ax.set_xlabel(x_label, fontweight='bold')` (the first manipulation of the Axes object in `drawplots()`), but the graph still looks identical to the second of the three plot images in the OP